# Не приходят данные на Server socket если данные начинаются со слова "OPTIONS"

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Написано тестовое серверное приложение, которое ждет клиентов на определенном порте. После соединения запускается ClientTask, которое обрабатывает конкретное соединение. (там getInputStream и после: read) Все работает хорошо до тех пор пока в начале посланных данных не встречается одно из зарезервированных команд HTTP, например OPTIONS. То есть, если клиент, допустим, посылает следующие данные: "OPTIONS asdfasdf", пакет не приходит и более того, соединение прерывается. У меня вопрос: какой сервис слушает мой частный открытый порт и решает что это HTTP запрос, а посколько HTTP запрос выполнен не по его стандарту, а по моему стандарту, то он останавливает соединение? Я хочу просто принять пакет, где есть случайно в начале слово OPTIONS или GET. Как я могу сделать, чтобы **мой** пакет, на **мой** порт приходили любые данные и чтобы они не определялись как HTTP команда? Если, просто для теста, послать с клиента правильный HTTP запрос, то команда проходит и нет никакого обрыва соединения.

Это приложение бежит на телефоне со статическим публичным IP, если это важно. Клиент - Windows приложение.
WireShark показывает что с IP телефона приходит пакет RESET если встречается одно из зарезервированных команд HTTP.

```
        final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
    Runnable serverTask  = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
```

Удалил все ненужное для читабельности

```
private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte readBuffer[] = new byte[10001];
        InputStream nis = null;
        System.out.println("Got a client ! "+ this.clientSocket.getLocalSocketAddress()+"      "+ this.clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
              clientSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(10000);
            nis = clientSocket.getInputStream();

    while(true) {
        int bytesReaded = nis.available();
        if (bytesReaded > 0) {
            bytesReaded = nis.read(readBuffer, 0, 10000);
            Log.i(TAG, "data arrived " +bytesReaded+ " bytes");
        }

    }
}}
```

Comment: Сами составляют какой-то сервис и сами же спрашивают, какой сервис отвечает на http-запросы. `ClientTask` - это Ваш класс или какой-то готовый использовали? Вы знаете что оно делает?

Comment: в ClientTask нет ничего такого. Это мой класс. Сначала вызывается getInputStream(), потом вызывается функция read. Сейчас добавлю

Comment: Вот и смотрите в своём `ClientTask` почему он не понимает options и другие команды http. Входной поток весь в Вашем распоряжении.

Comment: В том то и дело, что данные не приходят если есть в начале данных слово, например "OPTIONS". Нечего читать. WireShark на стороне клиента показывает что данные отправляются нормально

Comment: Предположим, что клиент с винды действительно подключается к этому сокету и на консоли можно наблюдать надпись `Got a client ! ...`. А `Log.i` что куда вводит? Может там тоде написать `System.out.println`? Хотелось бы убедится, что `Log.i` работает. Есть ещё одно предположение. Безумное правда. Андроид, видя такой код чтения потока, спешит пришибить такой сервис. Я бы на его месте так и поступил:) Бесконечный цикл, занимающий всё время процессора.

Comment: log.i выводит сообщение в консоль.

Comment: В данном случае `Log.i` действительно что-то выводит? Или программа обходит стороной строку вывода? Если выводит, тогда данные поступают. И ошибку следует искать в своей же программе, где входящие данные подвергаются анализу и обработке.

Comment: И ещё. Вы уверены, что available хоть когда нибудь возвращает не нулевое значение?

Comment: да, если данные от клиента не содержат в начале слово OPTIONS, то данные приходят, available возвращает значение. Вообще можно и без available, повешать его на Read и ждать синхронно. Тот же результат